# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} -1}{\sqrt{x} -1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} -1}{\sqrt{x} -1}$

I want to solve this limit by employing the strategy of introducing a new variable $t$ in such a way as to make the problem simpler.

I've tried using $t = \sqrt[3]{x} \Rightarrow \lim_{t \to 1} \frac{t -1}{\sqrt{t^3} -1}$ but I can't seem to manipulate the problem in to something simpler.

Can anybody give a hint?

Comment: Perhaps try x = t^6?

Comment: Many problems are based on the relations for the sum and difference of two cubes, which unfortunately are not taught as frequently as the "difference of two squares":  $$a^3 \ + \ b^3 \ = \ (a \ + \ b) \ (a^2 \ - \ ab \ + \ b^2) \ \ , $$ $$a^3 \ - \ b^3 \ = \ (a \ - \ b) \ (a^2 \ + \ ab \ + \ b^2) \ \ . $$

Comment: After @user_of_math's suggestion, use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @user_of_math great, I got it. Thank you.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434528/evaluating-lim-x-to-1-left-frac-sqrt3x-12-sqrtx-2-right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have$\require{cancel}$

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]x-1}{\sqrt x-1}=\frac{\cancel{(\sqrt[6]x-1)}(\sqrt[6]x+1)}{\cancel{(\sqrt[6] x-1)}(\sqrt[6]x^2+\sqrt[6]x+1)}\xrightarrow{x\to1}\frac23$$

Comment: I have a bad habit of only wanting to factor difference of squares and difference/sum of cubes when they factor 'nicely' like without containing roots for instance. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

We have: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x^{1/3} - 1}{x^{1/2} - 1} = \dfrac{\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x^{1/3} - 1}{x - 1}}{\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x^{1/2} - 1}{x - 1}} = \dfrac{(x^{1/3})'(1)}{(x^{1/2})'(1)} = \dfrac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{2}} = \dfrac{2}{3}$