# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, analysis

Evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}$$

---

My first idea was to multiply with

$$ \frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt[3]{x}-1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}+1} = \frac{x-1}{\sqrt[3]{x}-1} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+1} $$

Maybe we can somehow rearrange to use L'Hopital rule ? Or is there another way ?

EDIT: Thanks to the comments, we can continue.

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt[3]{x}-1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}+1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1} = \frac{(x-1)}{(x-1)} \cdot \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}+1} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}+1}$$

So we have

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}+1} = \frac{3}{2}$$

Credits to @AntonVrdoljak, @SammyBlack, @AlgTop1854, @DominikS, @Prem

---

This question looks similar but it is reciprocal & I am not sure if we can do the same :

[Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} -1}{\sqrt{x} -1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877128/evaluate-lim-x-to-1-frac-sqrt3x-1-sqrtx-1)

Comment: **Hint**: Multiply both the denominator and numerator with $\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1$.

Comment: *Alternative hint:* Let $x = u^6$ and substitute throughout to have a rational function (polynomial over a polynomial). Your $x \to 1$ becomes $u \to 1$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak How am I supposed to guess that we need to do that ? Is this some form of cubic conjugate ?

Comment: @SammyBlack Uh yes in fact that could be handy, I will try both ways, will report back soon

Comment: @wengen, that's exactly what it is: $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2) = a^3 - b^3$ with $a=\sqrt[3]{x}$ and $b=1$.

Comment: To @wengen: This action will result with $x-1$ in the denominator...

Comment: I like doing these by elementary means if possible too, but as a check L'Hopital applies directly and easily.

Comment: Duplicate, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624766/how-do-i-simplify-and-evaluate-the-limit-of-sqrt-x-1-sqrt3-x-1-as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of Alternatives & Variations given in the comments. Here are my ways :

Let $y=\sqrt[3]{x}-1$
Then $(y+1)^3=x$
Hence the given limit is :
$L=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}[\sqrt{(y+1)^3}-1]/y$

(1) This is $0/0$ , we can use LH rule.

$L=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}[(3/2)\sqrt{(y+1)}-0]/1$
$L=[(3/2)\sqrt{(0+1)}]$
$L=[3/2]$

(2) We can try without LH rule :
$L=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}[\sqrt{(1+y)^3}-1]/y$
Expanding , we get :
$L=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}[\sqrt{(1+3y+3y^2+y^3)}-1]/y$
$L=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}[(1+[3y+3y^2+y^3]/2+\text{ higher terms involving the variable })-1]/y$
$L=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}[(1+[3y+3y^2+y^3]/2+\cdots y^2 \cdots y^3 \cdots)-1]/y$
$L=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}[([3y+3y^2+y^3]/2+\cdots y^2 \cdots y^3 \cdots)]/y$
$L=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}[([3+3y+y^2]/2+\cdots y \cdots y^2 \cdots)]/1$
$L=[[3+0+0]/2+\cdots 0 \cdots 0 \cdots]$
$L=[3/2]$

There are other Substitutions which will work out to give Equivalent limit.